# encounter error with rendering album image

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

The error I encountered is a bit strange.
I build a music player on my website, and every functions of this music player I build works fine.

Let me show you the error first,

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cover')
MusicPlayer
D:/Github Projects/portfolio-website/src/components/Footer/MusicPlayer.jsx:199
  196 | <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
  197 |     <CoverImage>
  198 |         <img
> 199 |             alt={musicList[index].cover}
      | ^  200 |             src={musicList[index].cover}
  201 |         />
  202 |     </CoverImage>
```

The method I use to change the album cover is by create a useState. Whenever a song is skipped, the index will be set to increase by 1. If it is the last song in the list, the index will be set to 0, which is the first song.

To implement this, my music player has a skip next button. When clicked it will trigger a function called `handleSkipNext`

```
    const handleSkipNext = () => {

        console.log(index)

        if (index < musicList.length - 1) {
            audioRef.current.src = musicList[index + 1].source;
            audioRef.current.load();
            setIndex(index + 1);
        }

        if (index === musicList.length - 1) {
            audioRef.current.src = musicList[0].source;
            audioRef.current.load();
            setIndex(0);
        }

        audioRef.current.play();
        setPaused(false);
    }
```

If the a song is ended, it will trigger `handleSkipNext` too, with `onEnded`,

```
<audio id='audio' ref={audioRef} onLoadedMetadata={handleGetAudioData} onTimeUpdate={handleTimeUpdate} onEnded={handleSkipNext}>
    <source src={musicList[index].source} type="audio/mpeg"></source>
</audio>
```

I have tried to mess around with the music player, everything is fine.
This error seems to be appearing only when I let the song to end. Clicking the skip button does not trigger any problem. Seems to be the problem with `onEnded`.

```
 export const musicList = [
    {
        id: "1",
        title: "Ballade No.1 In G Minor, Op.23",
        source: "assets/audios/Ballade.mp3",
        cover: "assets/cover/pianist.jpg",
        artist: "Frédéric Chopin",
        performer: 'Janusz Olejniczak',
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        title: "",
        source: "assets/audios/jazz.mp3",
        cover: "assets/cover/jazz.jpg",
        artist: "Joe Hisaishi",
        performer: 'Cafe Music BGM channel',
    },
    {
        id: "3",
        title: "Kass' Theme",
        source: "assets/audios/Kass.mp3",
        cover: "assets/cover/zelda.jpg",
        artist: "The Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild OST",
        performer: "LEGEND OF ZELDA",
    },
];
```

Comment: Clearly, the error means that `index` is not a key in `musicList`. Using your debugging method of choice, find out what `index` is when it throws the error and go from there.

Comment: Code seems fine, are you sure you don't have a null/undefined at the end of your array? Does  `musicList.filter(Boolean)` have the same result?

Comment: I put console.log(index) at the start of my ```handleSkipNext```. Nothing is outputed in the console, so the error probably triggered before calling this function. If I click the skip button, index are correct everytime I skip a song, but if I wait for a song to end on itself, the error is triggered right after the onEnded function is fired. I just included my musicList in the original post.

Comment: What baffles me is my skip button onClick and onEnded triggers the same funciton, but only one getting error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the mistake I made. It's rather a stupid one.

Basically, the problem is not in the code I posted. In my `onTimeUpdate` function, I have `setIndex(index+1)` if time runs out for the song. Meanwhile, in `onEnded` function, I have another `setIndex(index + 1)`, so `index + 1` is trigger twice, which causes a looping problem, resulting in Javascript not finding the right path for my album cover.

I think I found a better logic to play the next song, without using the `onEnded` prop.

Here is my solution:

```
    const handleTimeUpdate = () => {
        if (audioRef.current) {
            setPosition(audioRef.current.currentTime)
        }


        if (timeLeft === 0) {
            handleSkipNext();
        }
    }
```

Very simple. If timeLeft reaches 0, it will trigger the skip song function.

```
    const handleSkipNext = () => {

        if (index < musicList.length) {
            setIndex(index + 1);
        }

        if (index === musicList.length - 1) {
            setIndex(0);
        }

        audioRef.current.load();

        setTimeout(() => {
            audioRef.current.play();
        }, 1000)
    }
```